# SGID write permissions in subfolder

Tags: linux, file, permissions

I create the folder "FolderA" with permissions:

```
drwsrwsr-x  5 user1 group1
```

when I create the subfolder "FolderB" with user2, who belongs to group1 it has following permissions:

```
drwsr-sr-x  5 user2 group1
```

Is there any possibility that this folder has automatically also group write permissions?

Regards.

Comment: you can use 'mkdir -m 0775' or change user2's umask: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uumask.htm

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

By default umask value is set to 022 which means all new files/folder created by any user will have permission 755 so you need to configure umask to 002 so new files/folder created by that user will automatically set permission to 775. 
You can update umask for any user in there home directory

$ vi ~/.bashrc
and add below line

umask 002

also you can update mask value for all user in
/etc/profile